# How does rails know if a string in postgres is a string or a serialized hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, hash

In rails, I have a hash that I "sanitized" and then inserted into the database with a direct sql call.
To read the record out, though I need to use the active record.  It however is reading the field as a string, though I have the serialize value set for that field.

Here's how I insert the data

```
def self.update_records(iFileName, iHashArray)
    return false if(rows.size == 0)  
    return false if(killed?)
    p "Pushing hash.size = #{rows.size}" 
    next_id = adjust_sequence( rows.size) #this reserves the record ids. explicit out paces the autosequence
    records = iHashArray.each_with_index.map { |hash, index|  "\r\n(#{next_id + index}, #{sanitize(hash)})" }
    sql = wrapWithSQL(UPLOAD_ID, sanitize(iFileName), records.join(", "));
    connection.execute(sql);
    adjust_sequence(1);
    return true
  end

  def self.wrapWithSQL(iUploadId, iFileName, iSql)
     sql = "WITH new_values (id, hash_value) as ( values #{iSql} )"+
           "\r\nINSERT INTO upload_stages (id, hash_value, upload_id, status,file_name, created_at, updated_at)"+
           "\r\nSELECT id, hash_value, #{iUploadId}, 1,  #{iFileName}, current_timestamp, current_timestamp FROM new_values  returning id";
end
```

My active record class for reading the values

```
class UploadStage < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize  :hash_value, Hash

  #...
end
```

Now on my windows box it works fine.  And for the last several months I've seen the hash come out without issue.
On heroku it comes out of the database as a string, and my code can't figure out what to do with a string when it was expecting a hash.

Has anyone any idea how to confront this?
Note... my pushing to the database with raw sql is because I'm pushing 5000 records in one go. I can alter the sql, but I have to be able to push with sql, because active record just doesn't support the speed I need.

Comment: I know this is old, but what was in the hash that you were putting into the database? Was it by chance a user-defined class? And why weren't you using to_yaml to convert the hash_value into a string?